# return timestamp value in store procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i'm trying to get timestamp value as result of stored procedure.
but getting error .
error message:- SQL Error [100132] [P0000]: JavaScript execution error: Incorrect Timestamp returned.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE simple_stored_procedure_example(awesome_argument VARCHAR)
returns TIMESTAMPNTZ 
language javascript
as
$$
var cmd = "SELECT EXTRACT_END_TIME FROM EXPLARITY_DB.EXPLARITY_SCHEMA.DEMO_CONTROL_TABLE WHERE PIPELINE_NAME =:1";
var sql = snowflake.createStatement(
                                {sqlText: cmd,
                                 binds: ['awesome_argument']
                                }
                                );
var result1 = sql.execute();
return result1;
$$;

CALL simple_stored_procedure_example('pipeline1');
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
create or replace table tst_tbl(c1 timestamp);
insert into tst_tbl values ('2021-02-02 10:00:00.000');

create or replace procedure my_test(myarg VARCHAR)
returns TIMESTAMP
language javascript
as
$$
var cmd = "SELECT c1 FROM tst_tbl";
var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
var resultSet = sql.execute();
resultSet.next();
my_date = resultSet.getColumnValue(1);
return my_date;
$$;

call my_test('test');
```

I get 1 row back as expected.